# Django and React Shopping Cart (request.session)

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('add/<int:id>/<slug:slug>/<int:quantity>/', views.cart_add),
    path('details/' , views.cart_details ),
]
```

**#views.py **

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def cart_add(request, id, slug, quantity):
    cart = request.session.get('cart' , {})

    
    product = get_object_or_404(Produit, id=id, slug=slug)

    
    cart[str(id)] = {"id" :id , "product": ProduitSerializer(product).data , "quantity": quantity}
    
    # Save the modified cart in the session
    request.session["cart"] = cart
    return Response({"cart": cart})
```

**//Cart.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";


export default function Cart(props){

    const [cart , setCart] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const cart_details = async () =>{
           try{
             const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/cart/details/`);
             console.log(response.data.cart)
             setCart(response.data.cart)
           }catch(err){
             alert(err)
           }
        }
        cart_details()
    },[])

    

    
    return (
    <section className="h-100" style={{backgroundColor :"#eee"}}>
      <div className="container h-100 py-5">
        <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      
 
 
 
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    )
}
```

1- When i try to add some product manual i can add it success , but when i try to add it from React , I can't .
2- when i try to get check http://localhost:8000/cart/details/ manual i can find the data added manualed , but when i try to get data from React i can't to .

I expect to get data from API

Answer (score 0):

Try changing urls.py like this

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('add/<int:id>/<slug:slug>/<int:quantity>/', cart_add.as_view()),
    path('details/' , cart_details.as_view()),
]
```